# C++ references and exiting scoping

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, scope

I'm getting to grips with references in C++ and I have a small query surrounding references & scoping, for this it's probably best to create an example:

Imagine I have a method in "BankDatabase.cpp" which takes a bank record by reference and adds it to a data structure (also by reference).

```
void AddRecord( BankRecord& bankRecord )
{
    //Add record to data structure by reference
}
```

If I run a method like so:

```
void TestAddRecord( BankDatabase& bankDatabase )
{
    BankRecord bankRecord { "John", "Doe", 9999 }
    bankDatabase.AddRecord( bankRecord );
}
```

To my mind, "bankRecord" falls out of scope (as do its two strings and int) and is thus cleared from memory at the end of the "TestAddRecord" method, leaving "bankDatabase" pointing at some empty memory?

If so what's the general accepted standard / resolution to such a scenario? It seems a little mad to have to pass things by value...

Answer (score 1):

In that case passing by value seems like the way to go. Allocating a new `BankRecord` pointer will work too. Storing things by reference is not very great.

However if I'm not mistaking, your two strings and the int won't be lost since they are present in the stack and will not be deallocated. But `bankRecord` will still be lost.

Comment: My concern is it doesn't seem particularly flexible, so for example if I were to add the record twice - bankDatabase.AddRecord( bankRecord ); bankDatabase.AddRecord( bankRecord ); - then they would be expected to share a reference but given a "pass by value" they wouldn't?

Comment: If you pass by value you make a copy of the variable. So it allocates two different elements. A reference or a pointer will not make a copy so it will be like you add the same record twice - which you seems to don't want.

Comment: @D.Nathanael Unfortunately we cannot make that assumption about pass by value and being copied because we don't know the specifics of underlying data structure. In some cases. You might be surprised to learn that passing by reference treats things differently than by pointer. For example, all the usual operators to the object apply, so it is in fact possible to make a copy of the object in his example even though it is passed by reference. This is a distinction programmers need to realize. I almost always prefer to use move semantics for adding objects to data structures to limit CTOR costs

Comment: @PaulRenton Oh ok! I always had in mind that a reference is a sugar for pointers, which is almost not false tho. So we need to know the storing data structure to tell if the reference is copied or not?

Comment: Yes, for example, what if AddRecord had several overrides, much like many common data structures have. If AddRecord's signature looked like this - AddRecord( varType object && ), it would use move semantics and not call a constructor more than once like a typical pass by value append might do. Also, some data structures do a POD data check internally and just do a memcopy. Sometimes it is just very important to challenge your assumptions and just step through the code to see what happens. It is good practice.

Comment: @D.Nathanael If you want to see an example of what I am talking about, look at all the std::vector functions that add elements to it. Start by looking at the differences between emplace, push_back, and others.

Comment: @D.Nathanael one last thing worth mentioning. A big distinction between a pointer and a reference is that a reference to an object can only be assigned one and cannot be assigned to nullptr (unless you perform an evil trick). Once a reference is assigned to an r-value, it will use all of the objects operators, including  the assignment operator, which as you might guess, will change how things work as opposed to a pointer being passed into a data structure where the above operators do not applied when assigning the same pointer from one object to another. Hope this helps

Comment: @PaulRenton thanks for your explanation, it's very nice to finally have a complete explanation of how references works!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to answer these concerns is to step through the code in the debugger and see what the Vector is doing with the variable being appended. Look especially at the constructor calls as you step into the data structure's Append functions. Because I do not know your underlying data structure, it is a bit more difficult for me to tell you more information. I will assume it is a std::vector for now until told otherwise.

You may be surprised to learn that references passed through a function do not tell the entire story about when it will go in and out of scope. I often think of C++ references as pointers that **do not need nullptr checks**.

Your code will work fine as long as the reference is copied into the vector or does not go out of scope because the variable it pointed to was destroyed. The reference will not go out of scope if it is referring to a member variable or memory on the heap for your particular case.

If the reference was declared on the stack to a variable created on the stack, and then appended to the vector, then you will have scope problems.

You should also look into emplace() if you have C++11 and the compiler supports move semantics.

In short, the most important thing you can do here is step through the code and see what Constructors are being called. This will give you the answer you desire.